# Odd Jobs for a scifi themed dnd thingy

Tags: science-fiction

I'm looking for different odd jobs that my players will able to. I want them to be a little more fun and random that differs from the serious tone of the main quest. They can be as random as you please but just have to be short n sweet. I currently have a variety of planets with different levels of technology advancement so anywhere from steampunk,cyberpunk and futuristic would work

Comment: [These forums are more suited to your question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go)

Comment: Hi, Welcome to RPG.stackexchange. You're question has been closed, but you can still take the [tour] and see what sort of questions we can answer here, and then feel free to ask more questions of your own.